# How do I rename a data-frame in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am very new to programming with R, but I am trying to read in multiple files for a directory and give them each a unique name.  I am reading the files in using the Dendrochronology Program Library in R (package dpIR) and the `read.tucson` function.  Although I'm using a specific package, I think my question is fairly general:

Within the loop, I want to create files by concatenating a `"t"` with each individual files name.  So, if I have a file named `"2503"` in my directory, I want to create a dataframe in R called `"t2503"`.  Next, I want to read the data in using the `r.tucson` function to each dataframe. Rather than assigning the read-in data to the dataframe, I'm just overwriting the concatenation with the data.  Can someone help me figure out what step I am missing?

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
#set to appropriate directory
setwd("C:/work")

#get a list of files in the directory
files <- list.files()
numfiles <- length(files)

for (i in 1:numfiles)
{
    name<-paste("t",files[i],sep="")
    name<-read.tucson(files[i],header=NULL)
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you gave the answer yourself: you have to use `?assign`.

Try something like that:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  assign(paste0("DF", i), data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10)))
}
```

This loops through the integers from 1 to 5 and creates five data.frames "DF1" to "DF5". For your example, you should just replace

```
name<-read.tucson(files[i],header=NULL)
```

with

```
assign(name, read.tucson(files[i],header=NULL))
```

Note, however, that `name` is a base function in R, so I would use another naming convention or just skip the first line:

```
assign(paste("t",files[i],sep=""), read.tucson(files[i],header=NULL))
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I tried using "assign" as you've outlined here and it did exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: WARNING: when you use `assign` in a function it behaves differently from using it at top level,  you'll need `env = .GlobalEnv` sooner or later.

Comment: That's a good advice. If the OP wants more information on that, he can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801208/assign-a-function-in-a-loop).

Comment: It is also best practice to read all the files into one list using `lapply` rather than clutter the environment with multiple objects (and doing global assignments is even worst.)

Comment: Thank you, everyone for your answers to my question.  I'm not sure I understand the warnings, since I'm still very new to R (have previously only used it for simple statistical analysis and less for data manipulation/programming).  But, it looks like I have some homework to do on understanding how "assign" and "lapply" differ.  Thank you,Katie

Comment: Thanks for answering the OP question instead of just lecturing him on the best practices. Sometimes the best practice does not fit one's task. My staff (not from IT) demanded me a code for a similar practical problem, and I found a bunch of questions with replies that just say what are the best practices, but did not provide a solution. This answer provides a solution.